# when deploying jar (spring boot 2 + react) to heroku - error 404

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, heroku, deployment

Making my own project (https://github.com/770001/buyer) based on https://blogg.kantega.no/webapp-with-create-react-app-and-spring-boot/. After deploying to heroku, I get 404 when the application starts, but the rest controller does not work. I can't figure out why. I fight for several days!

P.S. if I deploy the application following this tutorial, everything works. I don't understand why I have 404.
I tried the same thing with another tutorial - https://hackernoon.com/package-your-react-app-with-spring-boot-a-how-to-guide-cdfm329w - if you deploy it to heroku, everything works. But when I create my (identical) - 404.

Everything works for a localhost. I do via maven jar, run it via `java -jar target / <name jar file>` then run react via `cd frontend`, `yarn start`. Everything is working.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I added to the root folder of the application Procfile:

```
web java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/shmot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.8",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.6",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.khilkevichigor</groupId>
    <artifactId>shmot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>shmot</name>
    <description>International shopping</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>front</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v12.16.3</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>6.14.4</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/public">
                                    <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/front/build"/>
                                </copy>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is Build Log from heroku:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
-----> Executing Maven
       $ ./mvnw -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
       [INFO] Scanning for projects...
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] ----------------------< com.khilkevichigor:shmot >----------------------
       [INFO] Building shmot 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
       [INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ shmot ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:list (default-cli) @ shmot ---
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:install-node-and-npm (install node and npm) @ shmot ---
       [INFO] Installing node version v12.16.3
       [INFO] Unpacking /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/node/12.16.3/node-12.16.3-linux-x64.tar.gz into /tmp/build_ab545a20_/target/node/tmp
       [INFO] Copying node binary from /tmp/build_ab545a20_/target/node/tmp/node-v12.16.3-linux-x64/bin/node to /tmp/build_ab545a20_/target/node/node
       [INFO] Installed node locally.
       [INFO] Installing npm version 6.14.4
       [INFO] Unpacking /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/npm/6.14.4/npm-6.14.4.tar.gz into /tmp/build_ab545a20_/target/node/node_modules
       [INFO] Installed npm locally.
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (npm install) @ shmot ---
       [INFO] Running 'npm install' in /tmp/build_ab545a20_/front
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /tmp/build_ab545a20_/front/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
       [INFO] > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
       [INFO] > https://opencollective.com/core-js 
       [INFO] > https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] > core-js@3.8.2 postinstall /tmp/build_ab545a20_/front/node_modules/core-js
       [INFO] > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] > core-js-pure@3.8.2 postinstall /tmp/build_ab545a20_/front/node_modules/core-js-pure
       [INFO] > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] > ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /tmp/build_ab545a20_/front/node_modules/ejs
       [INFO] > node ./postinstall.js
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] Thank you for installing EJS: built with the Jake JavaScript build tool (https://jakejs.com/)
       [INFO] 
       [WARNING] npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents):
       [WARNING] npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
       [WARNING] npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents):
       [WARNING] npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
       [WARNING] npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.1 (node_modules/fsevents):
       [WARNING] npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
       [ERROR] 
       [INFO] added 1926 packages from 760 contributors and audited 1929 packages in 45.11s
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] 126 packages are looking for funding
       [INFO]   run `npm fund` for details
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] found 0 vulnerabilities
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.6:npm (npm run build) @ shmot ---
       [INFO] Running 'npm run build' in /tmp/build_ab545a20_/front
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] > front@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_ab545a20_/front
       [INFO] > react-scripts build
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] Creating an optimized production build...
       [INFO] Compiled successfully.
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] File sizes after gzip:
       [INFO] 
       [INFO]   41.69 KB  build/static/js/2.25b2f903.chunk.js
       [INFO]   1.39 KB   build/static/js/3.5c32b29a.chunk.js
       [INFO]   1.16 KB   build/static/js/runtime-main.f423ac52.js
       [INFO]   802 B     build/static/js/main.529d8860.chunk.js
       [INFO]   531 B     build/static/css/main.8c8b27cf.chunk.css
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
       [INFO] You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] The build folder is ready to be deployed.
       [INFO] You may serve it with a static server:
       [INFO] 
       [INFO]   npm install -g serve
       [INFO]   serve -s build
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] Find out more about deployment here:
       [INFO] 
       [INFO]   https://cra.link/deployment
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (default) @ shmot ---
       [INFO] Executing tasks
       
       main:
            [copy] Copying 19 files to /tmp/build_ab545a20_/target/classes/public
       [INFO] Executed tasks
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ shmot ---
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
       [INFO] Copying 1 resource
       [INFO] Copying 0 resource
       [INFO] The encoding used to copy filtered properties files have not been set. This means that the same encoding will be used to copy filtered properties files as when copying other filtered resources. This might not be what you want! Run your build with --debug to see which files might be affected. Read more at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filtering-properties-files.html
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ shmot ---
       [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
       [INFO] Compiling 15 source files to /tmp/build_ab545a20_/target/classes
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ shmot ---
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
       [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
       [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /tmp/build_ab545a20_/src/test/resources
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ shmot ---
       [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
       [INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /tmp/build_ab545a20_/target/test-classes
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ shmot ---
       [INFO] Tests are skipped.
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.3.1:war (default-war) @ shmot ---
       [INFO] Packaging webapp
       [INFO] Assembling webapp [shmot] in [/tmp/build_ab545a20_/target/shmot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
       [INFO] Processing war project
       [INFO] Building war: /tmp/build_ab545a20_/target/shmot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.1:repackage (repackage) @ shmot ---
       [INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
       [INFO] 
       [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ shmot ---
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_ab545a20_/target/shmot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/khilkevichigor/shmot/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/shmot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
       [INFO] Installing /tmp/build_ab545a20_/pom.xml to /tmp/codon/tmp/cache/.m2/repository/com/khilkevichigor/shmot/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/shmot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  01:14 min
       [INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-13T07:33:38Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 221.8M
-----> Launching...
       Released v22
       https://shmoting.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

This is application logs from heroku:

```
2021-01-13T07:32:15.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user khilkevichigor@gmail.com
2021-01-13T07:34:01.911760+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 1a70b985 by user khilkevichigor@gmail.com
2021-01-13T07:34:01.911760+00:00 app[api]: Release v22 created by user khilkevichigor@gmail.com
2021-01-13T07:34:03.105197+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-01-13T07:34:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-01-13T07:34:24.571031+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -Dserver.port=49823 $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/shmot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`
2021-01-13T07:34:27.415308+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2021-01-13T07:34:27.420758+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
2021-01-13T07:34:30.011053+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-01-13T07:34:30.011193+00:00 app[web.1]:   .   ____          _            __ _ _
2021-01-13T07:34:30.011284+00:00 app[web.1]:  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2021-01-13T07:34:30.011383+00:00 app[web.1]: ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2021-01-13T07:34:30.011477+00:00 app[web.1]:  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2021-01-13T07:34:30.011570+00:00 app[web.1]:   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2021-01-13T07:34:30.011668+00:00 app[web.1]:  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2021-01-13T07:34:30.013324+00:00 app[web.1]:  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.1)
2021-01-13T07:34:30.013382+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-01-13T07:34:30.433585+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:30.428  INFO 4 --- [           main] c.khilkevichigor.shmot.ShmotApplication  : Starting ShmotApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 1.8.0_275-heroku on affa4dd6-bc17-41aa-b83b-7290ef507210 with PID 4 (/app/target/shmot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war started by u5738 in /app)
2021-01-13T07:34:30.436511+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:30.436  INFO 4 --- [           main] c.khilkevichigor.shmot.ShmotApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-01-13T07:34:34.414783+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:34.414  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-01-13T07:34:34.670946+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:34.670  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 223 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-01-13T07:34:37.245660+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:37.244  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 49823 (http)
2021-01-13T07:34:37.288439+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:37.288  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-01-13T07:34:37.288893+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:37.288  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.41]
2021-01-13T07:34:39.683441+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:39.683  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-01-13T07:34:39.683661+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:39.683  INFO 4 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8934 ms
2021-01-13T07:34:40.337172+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:40.334  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-01-13T07:34:40.486708+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:40.485  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.25.Final
2021-01-13T07:34:41.135637+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:41.135  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-01-13T07:34:41.407961+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:41.407  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-01-13T07:34:42.079667+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:42.079  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-01-13T07:34:42.171030+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:42.170  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
2021-01-13T07:34:43.969250+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:43.968  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-01-13T07:34:43.987686+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:43.987  INFO 4 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-01-13T07:34:45.065217+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:45.064  WARN 4 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-01-13T07:34:47.509625+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:47.507  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@235a0c16, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@3401a114, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@73173f63, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@319bc845, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@5e8ac0e1, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4233e892, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@58ffcbd7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2b5f4d54, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@655ef322, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@25e2ab5a, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@37ddb69a]
2021-01-13T07:34:47.944922+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:47.944  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-01-13T07:34:48.163350+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:48.163  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [public/index.html]
2021-01-13T07:34:48.933082+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-01-13T07:34:48.717965+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:48.716  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 49823 (http) with context path ''
2021-01-13T07:34:48.745993+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-01-13 07:34:48.745  INFO 4 --- [           main] c.khilkevichigor.shmot.ShmotApplication  : Started ShmotApplication in 19.827 seconds (JVM running for 21.325)
```

It feels like React isn't working!

Comment: Where is your Procfile?

Comment: it is generated automatically by heroku, looks like this: `web
java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/buyer-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. When I deploy the repository from the tutorial - there is no `Procfile` there either, and heroku generates it itself - I see it on heroku -> dashboard -> overview

Comment: Ah ok, it is best always to create one, anyway in this case the generated one is what you would want. Any logs that can help `heroku logs`?

Comment: @BeppeC, I updated description, added pom and logs!